# Using <p> in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How can I display my text as it is, means if it has paragraph it should display in that way only?. I am using `<TextBlock>`.

For example.

hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.

kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.

lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll.

Thanx

Comment: "if it has paragraph" how is "paragraph" represented in your text?  A couple of newlines?  An actual html `<p>` ?  If you want support `<p>` does your text also contain other html elements?

Answer (score 3):

The TextBlock in Silverlight supports very simple formatting only. A RichTextBox (set IsReadOnly, with a few other formatting settings) might be a better choice in some situations.

You might try something like this when using a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Paragraph 1"/><LineBreak/><Run/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="Paragraph 2"/><LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="No visible break."/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="Paragraph 3"/><LineBreak/><Run/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="End"/>
</TextBlock>
```

That would produce a block of text like this:

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
No visible break.
Paragraph 3

End
```

If you had existing markup, you could use string replacement or regular expressions to do some of the adjustments for you. For example, this might work:

A `<p>` could be a `<Run>`.

A `</p>` could be a `</Run><LineBreak/><LineBreak/>`.

Comment: +1 on this.  I too would recommend RichTextBox if you really want much formatting - it has a <Paragraph> element that is closer to what you're looking for.  Only trouble is, RichTextBox isn't available on Windows Phone, so if you plan to port your app there, then TextBlock (and this answer) is better.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add the line breaks  yourself or divide it up in multiple  elements using code that loops through an array of all text that was split anywhere there was a line break.

This is how I fixed that:

```
public String Body { get; set; }

// Assign a string to Body

Body = Body.Replace("\n", "\n\n");
Body = Body.Replace("\r", "\r\r");
```

Then I assigned Body to the TextBlock:

```
txt_article.Text = Body;
```

Hope it helps :)